# ActiveX controls move when pushing XML data into Excel Table

Tags: excel, activex, ms-office, excel-2007, vba

I am pushing XML data into an Excel Table via C#, but when I do this, my ActiveX checkboxes lower on the page do not adjust their position. The spreadsheet rows move down, but the checkboxes do not.

Also, at times it seems like even though the cells on the spreadsheet shift down, the row heights do not, messing up the formatting.

I tried messing around with the properties of the checkboxes, but still got the same behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you set "Format Control / Properties" of your CheckBoxes to either "Move and size with cells" or "Move but don't size with cells"?

When you insert full rows the controls will move down.

When you just insert cell ranges with option "Shift cells down" you must ensure that the cell range boundaries (left/right) are wider than the space occupied by the controls (checkboxes including caption), as the control will be shifted down only in this case. So make your cell range larger or the Checkbox smaller.

Hope that helps - good luck - MikeD

Comment: Thanks.  We ended up using another solution, so this functionality wasn't needed.